# MySQL Хранимые процедуры. Вызов из PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

В MySQL создал хранимую процедуру. Не уверен, что правильно, т.к. необходимо ли в OUT указывать что вернуться может множество строк?:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `myProcedure` (IN id INT)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id = id;
END
```

1) Главный вопрос, как вызвать и как вызвать хранимую процедуру из PHP правильно, нужно ли использовать подготовленные запросы?

2) Вопрос возник, когда вызывал хранимую процедуру из phpMyAdmin используя `SQL CALL myProcedure(157)` отображалось 12 строк. При создании хранимой процедуры параметры OUT я не указывал. А при попытке вызвать `CALL myProcedure(9999)` с несуществующим ID я ожидал, что вернется 0 строк, а вернулось:

> Ошибка
>
> Статический анализ:
>
> Найдено 1 ошибок при анализе.
>
> Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "ON" at position 25)
>
> SQL запрос:
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> Ответ MySQL:
>
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Мне кажется что я что то сделал не так, т.к. при запросе с не существующем id должно вернуться просто 0 строк.

P.S: Запрос я упростил, возможно зря и это лишь собьет с толку. Вот полный запрос:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `getProductById` (IN id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT product.id, product.price, product.img, product.store_address, category.name, shop.name
    FROM product
    INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id
    INNER JOIN shop ON product.shop_id = shop.id
    WHERE category.id = id;
END //
```

Лучше использовать хранимую процедуру или функцию?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке никак не связано с вызовом процедуры, это походу "самодеятельность" используемой библиотеки/фреймворка.  У тебя  же нет в процедуре кода, вызывающего ошибку...

Comment: Процедуру я вызывал из phpMyAdmin SQL запросом

Comment: у меня сейчас такая же проблема, как решили этот вопрос?